# iTunes in Yosemite does not respond to media keys

Tags: macos, itunes

My media keys on my MBP for iTunes 12 in Yosemite don't respond. Spotify works fine. I'm using the <kbd>FN</kbd> key to access the standard F keys.

These all work:

- Screen brightness
- Expose
- Launch Pad
- Keyboard brightness
- Volume
- Power key

Is this a known issue or something I'm missing?

Comment: and it works if you do not use the Fn key ?

Comment: @buscar it doesn't work either way

Comment: did you try the Control-up/down arrow

Comment: @Buscar웃 i have that bound to something else.

Comment: sorry on iTunes 12 it is the cmd-up/down

Comment: those work fine but only when itunes is focused.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you happen to have Spotify or another media application open at the same time as iTunes? They'll hijack your media keys, passing the the controls to that application instead of iTunes.

Or perhaps Chrome is hijacking your media key keystrokes. You can get more information on that here: http://www.omgchrome.com/chrome-google-music-media-keys/

Comment: Happy to help! :)

Comment: I also got bit by Chrome on this. That's pretty annoying default behavior on their part.